# Joomla slow initial load, debug on

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, caching, joomla

So we use Joomla on our Intranet website, our network is all 1GB connections and 10GB at the servers so bandwidth is not an issue as to this loading problem.
Some background, the setup is on a VM running ubuntu 14.04 has all the updates (updates for 14.04). We are currently running Joomla 3.2.1, i want to update to current but i need to fix the loading issue first because it has slow loading on 3.5.2 as well.

So this happened out of no where, the website is where most of the employees go to submit forms and such to supervisors and higher ups. Randomly a few days ago/a week ago the site initial load time went from .8s to upwards of 1Min or 2 Mins to load.
I've tried turning cache on, compression on and no change.
cache on 15, compression off and no change
cache to 30, compression off and no change.
Checked the PHP config for any over or under allocation of memory or processing, nothing.
MySQL config for any over or under allocation, nothing.
.htaccess for correct permissions and modrewrite config, nothing wrong.

I have nothing info wise in the logs for anything that shows something running into errors or issues or loop loading.
I also migrated from a linux VM to an IIS7 VM and i still get inital load times that take forever. I am assuming it is some database issue but i don't know what.

I ran a repair on the database and everything came back ok. the VM has 8GB of RAM, 2 3.2GHz processor cores and does not use more then 20% processing on the cores and no more then 2GB of RAM our of 8GB.
I am beating my head on my desk trying to find why it's going so slow so if someone can have some insight please post up some ideas for me to try.
I have snapshots on the VM so anything i try i can revert back if needed.

Here are some debug snapshots as well, i know it is taking a while to load and query but to cause a page load time of 1-2mins??
http://postimg.org/gallery/1a4e0b27s/

Comment: Have you checked for the slow queries log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was going on, the SP Weather module that someone used and hid on one of the pages was outdated and the API was broken.

Disabled the module to check, loaded up in milliseconds. Ended up finding the update and updating to fix the current weather module. Everything loads in a matter of a second or less, and the weather now works again.

Answer (score 0):

20% is very high when it comes to load. We always try to maintain a load below 2. Anything above 2 means a slow website.

Let me give you a few tips:

- The RAM that you have is very small. You will need much more than that if you have many employees posting data. I would go with 64 GB. Your system is doing a lot of swapping and the fact that you probably don't have an SSD drive (I am assuming here, please correct me if I'm wrong) makes it worse.
- The MySQL slow query log should give you an idea what is going on. You can enable it in the my.cnf file.
- If you are using InnoDB, then it's almost a certainty that it is not properly configured in your my.cnf file (we are in the process of writing a post on how to configure it for Joomla websites, and once that post is finished I will share it here)

Comment: I would be interested in reading this post for my.cnf. Could you ping me here once you post it?

Comment: 64GB's probly won't work with our server, we might be able to up it but not to 64GB's. I'll run that by my boss but the fact that it isn't using more then 2GB's at anytime is going to throw questions. We do use a setup on SSD's actually, It has 4 10GB fiber channels to our all SSD storage. as for the 20% i am referring to that while i am SSH'd in, not during queries. During queries it uses maybe 5%, and another thing is that this just happened out of no where after 2-3 years of non stop use. I could be wrong but i am just posting more detailed info on whats going on not saying you are wrong.

Comment: As for InnoDB it is used, i am unsure about the options i should change/use because one post i read something something different then the other.  Not sure what off of My.cnf you need but heres some settings:

key_buffer  = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 16M
thread_stack  = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
query_cache_limit = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
expire_logs_days = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet = 16M